# Reading Image url via CSV upload in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a CSV file that has an image URL as one of the fields. I'm using paperclip to process images in my Rails 4 app. Here is the import code in my model. Can you tell me what's wrong with the below syntax - specifically the URI parsing code? If I remove the image field from my CSV file, everything uploads correctly.

I want rails to get the jpg file from the url and save it on our server. It's an ecommerce app so I'm trying to load product images for each product.

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|


  listing_hash = {:name => row['Name'], :description => row['Description'], 
  :price => row['Price'], :image => URI.parse.row['Image'] }

  listing = Listing.where(id: listing_hash["id"])

  if listing.count == 1
    listing.first.update_attributes(listing_hash)
  else
    Listing.create!(listing_hash)
  end # end if !product.nil?
end # end CSV.foreach
end # end self.import(file)
```

Comment: Are you getting a `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
:image => URI.parse.row['Image']
```

You should be passing `row['Image']` to the `parse` method like this:

```
URI.parse(row['Image'])
```

Comment: I tried that first and it didn't work either. Any other thoughts? Do I need to write any URI specific code in any other file?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work". Was there an exception?

Comment: sorry, it worked. i had another minor issue that i fixed. thanks Diego.